# How to parametrize initial text at TextEditingController

Tags: flutter, dart, texteditingcontroller

Cannot find a clue why i can't set an initial text at TextEditingController as the parameter:
following code works well:

```
TextEditingController _usernameController =
  TextEditingController(text: 'test');
```

But if i change hardcoded value to a parameter it brokes:

```
String _test = 'test';

TextEditingController _usernameController =
    TextEditingController(text: _test);
```

How to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
String _test = 'test';
TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();

...
TextFormField(
         controller: _usernameController..text = this._test,
```